# Why is computatorium considered to be a better word than computatrum? (For the English word "computer")

Tags: vocabulary, word-comparison, new-latin

I was watching a Luke Ranieri video in which he mentioned that computatrum isn't a very good word for computer, and that computatorium is much better, and that people should stop using computatrum. Here's the timestamp link for when he says that: (He says it at 3:39 in case the timestamp doesn't work)

https://youtu.be/iNTEW0PNqjU?t=219

I was just wondering, why is computatorium considered to be a much better word?

Comment: It seems that form which would have been expected in classical times would be *computāculum*. Read notes in [-culum](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-culum#Latin), [-trum](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-trum#Latin), [-torium](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-torium#Latin).

Comment: *Computatorium* sounds like a place where people gather to compute… anyway, why don't you ask him, he has comments allowed on his video.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel Because the way he was talking about it made it sound as if it was a common stance/consensus, not just something he alone says.